# Getting the name of a function provided to an Ember `action` helper

Tags: ember.js

I'm assuming this isn't possible, but wanted to see if anyone knew any better.

With ES6, you can get the name of a function. For instance:

```
function foo() { return true; }
function bar() { return true; }

const functionContainer = foo;

foo.name; // 'foo'
bar.name; // 'bar'
functionContainer.name; // 'foo'
```

In Ember, you can pass an action into an action helper. For instance:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    bar() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

And the template:

```
{{foo-component foo=(action "bar")}}
```

Within `foo-component`, is there some way to do this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  doFoo: Ember.on('didRecieveAttrs', function() {
    console.log(this.attrs.foo.name); // 'bar'
  })
});
```

When I try, I just get a blank string. This makes sense, since it looks like the `bar` action is getting wrapped in a nameless function by `ember-metal`.

Anyone know of a way to grab that name? It would make a huge difference for a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't do exactly what you want < insert technical discussion about closures here >, but you can kinda fake it by just adding another param to your component, like so:

```
{{foo-component foo=(action "bar") actionName="bar"}}
```

then in your component.js you can access

```
this.attrs.actionName // "bar"
```